# Per-Pixel operation with conditonals in Python without slowy loops

Tags: python, image, loops, conditional-statements, pixel

I'm trying to apply a treshold to an image, but not a regular simple treshold.

I need to set to black pixels if they fit the conditonal, and if not, set them to white.

I could just loop over pixels, but on a 1080p image, it's far too long.

I'm using HSV for the comparisons I need to make.

Here is the conditional (this example is how I would use it if it was in a loop):

```
if abs(input_pixel_color.hue - reference.hue) < 2 and input_pixel_color.saturation >= 0.25 and input_pixel_color.brightness >= 0.42:
    set_to_black
else:
    set_to_white
```

`input_pixel` is the HSV value of the pixel in the loop.

`reference` is a variable to be compared to.

I thought about using numpy, but I really don't know how to write this :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should definitely be using Numpy, or OpenCV. Which library are you using to load and save your images?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using OpenCV to load my images, but with OpenCV functions, i'm not sure you can do this kind of stuff.
For numpy, i'm struggling to visualize the 3D array and to find the right function to use to apply the condtionnal.

Comment: For numpy, i could use np.where, but i can't seems to find how to apply condtionnals on a specific value. If i set something like where(a > 3), it will check H, S and V values for each pixel, but i only want H value in this case.

I would only want to get the first value of a row i think

Comment: In your new code there are some issues. Decide whether you are using HSV or HLS and use the correct converters (cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV or cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS) AND corresponding indices into arrays. You don't use LightnessOK. You have saved the result of `np.where()` into a new array of a different shape and dtype. Your final `cvtColor()` is unneeded, your image is grey already.

Comment: Try and get in the habit of using IPython or your debugger and checking the `shape` and `dtype` of your arrays at each point, or convert your mask to an image and look at it to check it's correct. `tmp=(HueOK*255).astype(np.uint8)` then display or save it and check.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i wanted to use HSV at the beginning, but decided that HLS easier to be on par with other code parts, so i'm gonna stick to HLS.

Comment: To be sure i'm understanding this correctly :  

I have an opencvimage (aka a np.array), in BGR format (default format for imread),   then i convert it to HLS with  
`hsl_arr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)`  
My values (that i use to filter) :  
Hue (Val from 0 to 360)  
Saturation (% from 1 to 100, in this example, my val is 0.25, for 25%)  
LightNess (% from 1 to 100, in this example, my val is 0.42, for 42%)

Comment: I think the Hue is in the right format, but i'm not sure for Saturation and Lightness.    
First question : Does the 'BGR2HLS' in the opencv conversion stand for   Hue/LightNess/Saturation (so it's not in the same order as HSL), or it's just a typo   Mistake ?  

Right now i'm confused by the order and the format of these three values, thats why my code doesn't really produce results.  
 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I also compared the BGR array and HSL, and the results doesn't match with the online convertor. @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Now that your actual intended processing has become clearer, you would probably be better served by **OpenCV** `inRange()` function. Like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3 

import cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np 

# Load the image and convert to HLS 
image = cv.imread("image.jpg") 
hls   = cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2HLS) 

# Define lower and uppper limits for each component 
lo = np.array([50,0,0]) 
hi = np.array([70,255,255]) 

# Mask image to only select filtered pixels 
mask = cv.inRange(hls,lo,hi) 

# Change image to white where we found our colour 
image[mask>0]=(255,255,255) 

cv.imwrite("result.png",image)
```

So, if we use this image:

[image]

We are selecting Hues in the range 50-70, and making them white:

[image]

If you go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp) to a colour converter, you can see that "Green" is Hue=120, but **OpenCV** divides Hues by 2 so that 360 degrees becomes 180 and still fits in a uint8. So, our 60 in the code means 120 in online colour converters.

[image]

The ranges OpenCV uses for uint8 images are:

- Hue 0..180
- Lightness 0..255
- Saturation 0..255

As I said before, you should get in the habit of looking at your data types, shapes and ranges in your debugger. To see the `shape`, `dtype`, and maximum Hue, Lightness and Saturation, use:

```
print(hls.dtype, hls.shape) 
print(hls[...,0].max())
print(hls[...,1].max())
print(hls[...,2].max())
```

**Original Answer**

There are several ways to do that. The most performant is probably with the **OpenCV** function `cv2.inRange()` and there are plenty of answers on StackOverflow about that.

Here is a Numpy way. If you read the comments and look at the printed values, you can see how to combine logical AND with logical OR and so on, as well as how to address specific channels.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from random import randint, seed 
import numpy as np

# Generate a repeatable random HSV image
np.random.seed(42)
h, w = 4, 5
HSV = np.random.randint(1,100,(h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8)
print('Initial HSV\n',HSV)

# Create mask of all pixels with acceptable Hue, i.e. H > 50
HueOK = HSV[...,0] > 50
print('HueOK\n',HueOK)

# Create mask of all pixels with acceptable Saturation, i.e. S > 20 AND S < 80
SatOK = np.logical_and(HSV[...,1]>20, HSV[...,1]<80)
print('SatOK\n',SatOK)

# Create mask of all pixels with acceptable value, i.e. V < 20 OR V > 60
ValOK = np.logical_or(HSV[...,2]<20, HSV[...,2]>60)
print('ValOK\n',ValOK)

# Combine masks
combinedMask = HueOK & SatOK & ValOK
print('Combined\n',combinedMask)

# Now, if you just want to set the masked pixels to 255
HSV[combinedMask] = 255
print('Result1\n',HSV)

# Or, if you want to set the masked pixels to one value and the others to another value
HSV = np.where(combinedMask,255,0)
print('Result2\n',HSV)
```

**Sample Output**

```
Initial HSV
 [[[93 98 96]
  [52 62 76]
  [93  4 99]
  [15 22 47]
  [60 72 85]]

 [[26 72 61]
  [47 66 26]
  [21 45 76]
  [25 87 40]
  [25 35 83]]

 [[66 40 87]
  [24 26 75]
  [18 95 15]
  [75 86 18]
  [88 57 62]]

 [[94 86 45]
  [99 26 19]
  [37 24 63]
  [69 54  3]
  [33 33 39]]]
HueOK
 [[ True  True  True False  True]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True False False  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True False]]
SatOK
 [[False  True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False  True]
 [ True  True False False  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True]]
ValOK
 [[ True  True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True False  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False]]
Combined
 [[False  True False False  True]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True False False False  True]
 [False  True False  True False]]
Result1
 [[[ 93  98  96]
  [255 255 255]
  [ 93   4  99]
  [ 15  22  47]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[ 26  72  61]
  [ 47  66  26]
  [ 21  45  76]
  [ 25  87  40]
  [ 25  35  83]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [ 24  26  75]
  [ 18  95  15]
  [ 75  86  18]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[ 94  86  45]
  [255 255 255]
  [ 37  24  63]
  [255 255 255]
  [ 33  33  39]]]
Result2
 [[  0 255   0   0 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0   0 255]
 [  0 255   0 255   0]]
```

**Notes**:

1) You can also access pixels not selected by the mask, using negation:

```
# All unmasked pixels become 3
HSV[~combinedMask] = 3
```

2) The ellipsis (`...`) is just a shortcut meaning *"all other dimensions I didn't bother listing"*, so `HSV[...,1]` is the same as `HSV[:,:,1]`

3) If you don't like writing `HSV[...,0]` for Hue, and `HSV[...,1]` for Saturation, you can split the channels

```
H, S, V = cv2.split(HSV)
```

Then you can just use `H` instead of `HSV[...,0]`. When you are finished, if you want to re-assemble the channels back into a 3-channel image, you can do:

```
HSV = cv2.merge((H,S,V))
```

or

```
HSV = np.dstack((H,S,V))
```

Comment: `Updated
Now that your actual intended processing has become clear, you would probably be
better served by OpenCV inRange() function, see here.`




I was before using this method to treshold, but now that i basically have different operations on each H, S and L, i don't see how can i use an cv2.inrange to do this. (But it must be because i don't catch the simple things sometimes ^^)

Comment: First, thanks a lot for answering me ! It's a very complete answer and exactly what i tried to do ! I changed my code following your example, but it seems to just output one '255' per row in the resulting array, so it kinda break the image :

Comment: Here is my attempt :

    `image = cv2.imread(input_file) # BGR
    hsl_arr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
    
    HueOK = np.logical_and(hsl_arr[...,0]>44, hsl_arr[...,0]<48)
    SaturationOK = hsl_arr[...,1] >= (0.25 * 255)
    LightnessOK = hsl_arr[...,2] >= (0.42 * 255)
    
    combinedMask = HueOK & SaturationOK
    final_arr = np.where(combinedMask,0,255)
    final_img = cv2.cvtColor(final_arr, cv2.COLOR_HLS2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('test', final_img)`

Comment: I printed the "final_arr" inside a txt file, and it show something like :

255.00

255.00

255.00

etc...

Thx in advance for your answers !

Comment: Please don't put swathes of code in the comments area, it is unformatted and really hard to read. Instead, please click `edit` under your question and put it in there making sure your question is complete, up-to-date and all in one place.